# Selenium + Chromedriver +Excel VBA. Change the download directory multiple time in single code

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a excel macro to download certain files from a website.
I have changed the default download directory. Now, in that I want to download certain documents in specific sub folders. But i am not able to change the download directory once the default directory is set.
Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
    Dim driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\Folder\"
    driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
    driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False

    driver.Get "https://www.google.com/"
```

The "C:\Folder" is where you put the folder you want.

Comment: Yes, I was able to set the preference for download. But later in the code, I want to change that preference for a certain download. How can I change the download folder later in the code?