# SetPreference in Edge for change directory download

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I need to change the directory where I'll save a file coming from the download after clicking a link. I was able to find and click on the link, but I need to set the location and name of the file.
I'm using VBA

Comment: I made a test with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424206/selenium-chromedriver-excel-vba-change-the-download-directory-multiple-time/63494298#63494298), but it seems that it only works with Chrome. I don't find other solutions for Edge. AFAIK, VBA uses SeleniumBasic to do automation which uses Selenium version 2. The version is too old and I suggest that you can use other languages with the latest version of Selenium. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp#using-selenium-4).

Comment: In this time i can't change my languages. I'm try this code in chrome  
    driver.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\Folder\"
    driver.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
    driver.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
and doesn't work.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does it show any error? I can change the download folder using the code. Do you create the folder you want to change to and point to it in the code? Do you use the same version of Chrome WebDriver as the Chrome browser?